# Is there a compatibility library for/way to use NotificationBuilder on Gingerbread and below?

Tags: android, notifications

I like the ease of use of NotificationBuilder, and need to update my notification frequently.
Is there a way I can use this fantastic class on earlier versions of Android?

Comment: Huh? I didn't get any answers.

Comment: you have asked 7 questions, out of which 4 has been answered.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. Anything about this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Android Support package contains `NotificationCompat.Builder`, that supplies a backport of `Notification.Builder` for use on API Level 4 and higher.

Comment: Thanks I was struggling with this too, easy solution.